# MyBatis - how to define array in mybatis xml mapper file

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-mapper

I would like to define array of string in mybatis mapper and pass it as argument for java static method.
It's possible?

Comment: I don't think there's an out of the box TypeHandler for it (I may be wrong). However, it should be pretty straightforward to write one for arrays. See https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers. Essentialy, you just need to create a class that extends https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/org/apache/ibatis/type/TypeHandler.html and then tell MyBatis which column(s) should use it (while reading and storing data).

Comment: Maybe there is an out of the box Array Type Handler, but I haven't tried it. See https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/org/apache/ibatis/type/ArrayTypeHandler.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one solution, I can define array in 'bind' tag and then pass it to method as argument:

```
        <bind name='exampleArray' value='{"one", "two", "three"}'/>
        ${@com.example.MybatisUtil@generate(exampleArray)}
```